# HTTP 400 Bad Request on Flask app with cUrl

Tags: python, http, curl, flask

I am attempting to do a basic request on my Flask-app with cUrl.

This is my Flask code:

```
@application.route('/fb_checkin/', methods=['POST'])
def checkin():
    qr_code = request.form['qr']
    provider_name = request.form['provider']

    #Lookup Access Key by qr in database
    resp = requests.post("https://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<DOMAIN>.cloudant.com/socialmattic_users/_find",
                         '{"selector": {"qr": "' + qr_code + '"}}')

    token = resp.json()['fb_access_token']
```

This is my curl command:

`curl -X POST 'localhost:5000/fb_checkin/?qr=default&provider=void'`

After issuing the curl command an HTTP 400 error is returned.

Is anyone able to tell me why this is the case?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you provide complete response from curl (use `-v` to get more verbose information)?

Comment: Do you run the application in debug mode? Is log file providing any more detail? It would be great, if you would provide complete running code - it make investigation much simpler (of course best is a code which runs, but is as short as possible).

Comment: that is because your method is post and your sending through get method

Answer (score 3):

curl should be and also no quotes to URL

```
curl --data "qr=default&provider=void" http://localhost:5000/fb_checkin/
```

Comment: Downvote without comment is lame. make me learn from my mistakes